# Join column with timestamps where value is maximum

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like

```
+-------+-----------+
| value | timestamp |
+-------+-----------+
```

and I'm trying to build a query that gives a result like

```
+-------+-----------+------------+------------------------+
| value | timestamp | MAX(value) | timestamp of max value |
+-------+-----------+------------+------------------------+
```

so that the result looks like

```
+---+----------+---+----------+
| 1 | 1.2.1001 | 3 | 1.1.1000 |
| 2 | 5.5.1021 | 3 | 1.1.1000 |
| 3 | 1.1.1000 | 3 | 1.1.1000 |
+---+----------+---+----------+
```

but I got stuck on joining the column with the corresponding timestamps.

Any hints or suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

For further information (if that helps):
In the real project the max-values are grouped by month and day (with group by clause, which works btw), but somehow I got stuck on joining the timestamps for max-values.

**EDIT**

Cross joins are a good idea, but I want to have them grouped by month e.g.:

```
+---+----------+---+----------+
| 1 | 1.1.1101 | 6 | 1.1.1300 |
| 2 | 2.6.1021 | 5 | 5.6.1000 |
| 3 | 1.1.1200 | 6 | 1.1.1300 |
| 4 | 1.1.1040 | 6 | 1.1.1300 |
| 5 | 5.6.1000 | 5 | 5.6.1000 |
| 6 | 1.1.1300 | 6 | 1.1.1300 |
+---+----------+---+----------+
```

**EDIT 2**

I've added a fiddle for some sample data and and example of the current query.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/efa42/1

How to add the corresponding timestamp to the maximum?

Comment: You seem to have left out your schema definitions / sample data. It is much more difficult to help you without useful sample data to work from. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is useful for this. Otherwise we all have to make our own dummy data up, slowing down answering of other useful questions. If you happen to edit your question to add sample data, please comment after you do so and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've added the fiddle. Hope that helps

Comment: @mjreaper Can you please validate my answer if it's what you were looking for !?

Answer (score 2):

Try a cross join with two sub queries, the first one selects all records, the second one gets one row that represents the time_stamp of the max value, <3;"1000-01-01"> for example.

```
SELECT col_value,col_timestamp,max_col_value, col_timestamp_of_max_value FROM table1
    cross join
      (
        select max(col_value) max_col_value ,col_timestamp col_timestamp_of_max_value  from table1
        group by col_timestamp
        order by max_col_value desc
        limit 1
      ) A --One row that represents the time_stamp of the max value, ie: <3;"1000-01-01">
```

Comment: Could you provide some comments along with your query?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg The query represents a cross join with two sub queries, the first one is all the records, and the second one (A) gets one row that represents the time_stamp of the max value, ie: <3;"1000-01-01">.

Comment: That looks good at first, but how to group by month and year? (group by col_timestamp, date_part('month', col_timestamp)) did'nt work...

Answer (score -1):

Use the window cause you use with pg

```
 Select *, max( value ) over (), max( timestamp ) over() from table
```

That gives you the max values from all values in every row

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html